# Looking for a translation of '舒适性‘ and '安全性'?

Tags: translation

该品牌汽车以优良的舒适性和安全性赢得了众多车主的喜爱。

This brand of automobile uses first rate *comfortness and *safetyness to win many car owner's favour.

Comment: If I accept 1 answer I risk offending the authors of the other answers. It is not always easy to say: "This is the best answer." Why are you researching my old questions? If you want more points, I'll vote for your answers, don't worry.

Answer (score 2):

安全性

> safety; safeness -*ABC*
>
> safety, security -*KEY*

I would just translate both as **safety** and **comfort**.

I guess you want to try and translate the 性 as accurately as possible but if you look at the definitions above they don't get super "-ized" or "-ness"-y.

Comment: Would the sentence then still be good Chinese if I left out the 2 ‘性’？？
‘该品牌汽车以优良的舒适和安全赢得了众多车主的喜爱。’

Comment: The Chinese kinds of needs it, but translation is a whole other story. If I were to translate the sentence I would flip the whole thing around: *Consumers love was won over by this manufactures superior saftey and comfort.* never translate word for word, you will only end up with Chinglish that way!

Comment: Thanks. I always try to follow the Chinese first, then move it around after. When I improve, I might be able to miss out the first stage!

Answer (score -1):

Not very good if left out 性 ,性 means property here.安全性 and 舒适性 refer to the "safe and comfortable property" of the car.It's more proper to use these words in this circumstance.

Here,the structure is 
该品牌汽车以
(优良的舒适性和安全性)(noun)
赢得了众多车主的喜爱。

If you use 优良的安全和舒适 as the noun part here,it is a bit strange.

Comment: But OP is looking for English, so you'd have to think of this from an English standpoint: what would the sentence be if written in English?

Comment: I was just trying to reply to a previous comment but the system told me I could not post a comment now ,so I posted it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks you guys! I think I've got it! As far as I see it, the basic sentence is:
舒适性和安全性赢得了喜爱。
Comfort and safety win favour.